# Saving user data in swift and making a decision using the data (iOS app dev)

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I am asking the user to sign up for an account. I am not using a backend as this app is being made for the sake of user interface design learning. I want to save the user's email and password, so when he/she logs in I can use an if statement to confirm and allow the user to proceed using the app. What is the best way of doing this? I am using Xcode 6.3 right now. I am very new to swift - learning on my own for the class. Any help would be appreciated. I've tried to find solutions but they are using obj C.

Comment: You can just save the username & password selected in `NSUserDefaults` and compare against the saved values

Answer (score 2):

You should use `NSUserDefaults`!

It's a bit like `SharedPreferences` in android. It's like a `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`. You save stuff into it using key-value pairs.

Here's an example:

You want to save the email, right? Just do this:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(usersEmailHere, forKey: "email")
```

The above code saves the email as a value and the string `"email"` as the key. You can get the email back by using the same key:

```
let email = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("email")
```

Super-duper easy!

However, if you want to store multiple users' emails, I suggest that you use Core Data instead of `NSUserdDefaults` because `NSUserDefaults` is used to save small amounts of data.

Comment: Where exactly would I write this code, in my view controller .h file?

Comment: @user3874530 Wait. I thought you were using swift. There is no .h file in Swift. Anyway, you should write this code after the user logged in maybe? I actually don't know what you want to achieve.